# Why `<< String.reverse("Halo") >>` is not allowed in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Why is this OK,

```
iex(23)> << "Halo" >>
"Halo"
```

while this is not OK in Elixir?

```
iex(24)> << String.reverse("Halo") >>
** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have an expression inside `<< >>`, the type of that expression is assumed to be an integer representing one byte by default.

```
iex(1)> << trunc(65.2) >>
"A"
iex(2)> << trunc(1000.3) >>
<<232>>
```

If your expression is a binary (also called a String in Elixir), you need to specify the type of the expression explicitly:

```
iex(3)> << String.reverse("Halo")::binary >>
"olaH"
```